# rsync --exclude 'folder', copies that folder anyway

Tags: bash, find, backup, rsync

There are a lot of posts about this, I know, but I tried all and still can't get it working.

If this is my folder to backup: `/home/user/thingstobackup`
the script will create a "backup" folder here and inside another folder named as the date of today. The daily backup is copied inside.

No matter how I use rsync, the "backup" folder will be always copied inside itself starting from the 2nd run of the script.

1st run:

```
/home/user/thingstobackup
/home/user/thingstobackup/backup/2016-01-13 #and correct file inside
```

2nd run:

```
/home/user/thingstobackup/backup/2016-01-13 #with correct file inside
/home/user/thingstobackup/backup/2016-01-14 #with correct file inside
```

I will shorten the path here..

```
../backup/2016-01-14/2016-01-13/and backed up file inside..
../backup/2016-01-14/backup/
../backup/2016-01-14/backup/2016-01-13/and backed up file inside..
../backup/2016-01-14/backup/2016-01-14/empty
```

After the 2nd run, the backup folder is copied inside every daily backup folder.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin

# directory to backup
TOSAVE=/home/user/thingstobackup
TODAY=`date +%F`
BDIR=backup
BACKUPDIR=$TOSAVE/$BDIR/$TODAY/

# options for rsync
OPTS="-aq --exclude='backup/*'"

# find daily new file
FIND="`find $TOSAVE -mindepth 1 -mtime -1 -print`"

# MAIN #

# copy daily found inside new created daily folder
[ -d $TOSAVE/$BDIR/$TODAY ] || mkdir -p $TOSAVE/$BDIR/$TODAY
rsync $OPTS $FIND $BACKUPDIR

# delete file older than 2 weeks = 14 days
find $TOSAVE -mtime +14 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

No matter how I use `--exclude='backup/*'"` `--exclude='backup'` || `--exclude 'backup/*'` || `--exclude 'backup'`

It does not exclude that folder.. Yes I read the rsync manual: `--exclude=PATTERN       exclude files matching PATTERN`

I'm sure I'm missing something but I just can't find it! Thanks in advance mates

Comment: No it didn't change :/

Comment: Why not use the `--backup-dir=` option with rsync... it's meant for incremental backups.

Comment: Something like ??:
OPTS="-aq --exclude '/backup' --backup-dir=$BACKUPDIR" 
rsync $OPTS $FIND 

Well, the script works as it is, but it also copies this backup folder which should not.. Not a problem to change that but I'd prefer to resolve the exclude thing

BTW, this is not an incremental backup. All the files inside /thingstobackup/ are new file generated each day. So that's why must be copied inside a daily folder. They are not the same

Comment: The problem is that you are creating the backup directory each time the script runs and placing it before the $today directory. That is why you end up with possibly endless nested directories. Normally you would want the dated directory first, then the backup content within that (eg. `../$TODAY/$BDIR`)

Comment: [ -d $TOSAVE/$BDIR/$TODAY ] || mkdir -p $TOSAVE/$BDIR/$TODAY

The first run it creates the backup folder (thanks to mkdir -p)
and the second run it will create the new day-folder inside the backup, which is created already. Probably you're right but I don't find this to be the issue, do you? can you please tell me why? The condition should run smooth :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why --exclude does not work here.. but I modified the find command and I managed to let this thing work.

```
FIND="`find $TOSAVE -mindepth 1 -type d \( -path $TOSAVE/backup \) -prune -o -mtime -1 -print`"
```

Comment: Actually I think you've got multiple issues in your script, although for the `--exclude` it would most likely work as `--exclude=backup` (without quotes around it).

Comment: @I'L'I Please point me the issues as I'm not skilled in bash scripting and your hints could help me

Comment: I'll post a new version of your script if that helps; first though, are you trying to rsync all the files in `thingstobackup` or only folders in that directory? I ask because if it's regular files (not just folders) it matters in the options you specify.

Comment: Yes it might help, I build this script from things taken here and there but I gave the shape I wanted and I actually thought it was good.. Anyway.. inside thingstobackup there are no folders (except for backup), there are many file with many different extension.
At the moment there are some thousands file.
I don't need them anymore. I will keep everything clean with removing everyday file older than 14 days.
The script runs every night. it will backup long and short name file with several extension which last update was 1 day ago. The same will be removed after 2 weeks BUT backup folder remain

Comment: Your script isn't bad, although it does have a few things which are either redundant, old style bash syntax, or other little mistakes.

Comment: "old style bash syntax" yeah.. I'm old for this s**t but please don't say that out loud eheh!! JK. I started practicing with linux back in 2002 but I tend to prefer Microsoft sometimes. My bash knowledge is not awesome but it works, and I got that going for me, which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

[@Nihvel was right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34788899/rsync-exclude-folder-copies-that-folder-anyway#comment57322001_34788899):

```
cd -- "$(mktemp --directory)"
mkdir foo bar
touch foo/foo bar/bar
other="$(mktemp --directory)"
rsync --recursive --exclude 'foo' * "$other"
ls "$other" # prints only "bar"
```

This works whether the local file specifier is `*` (as above), `./*` or `/tmp/tmp.MGUbytm0h0/*`, and whether `$PWD` is `/tmp/tmp.MGUbytm0h0` or something else.

Comment: I must thank you for your example mate, it is a bit too hard for me to read but looks indeed what I'd need. Anyway I solved fixing the find command which to me looks easier to implement in my script! Thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix the `--exclude` issue by not putting quotes around the option or by including a space instead of using `=`; `rsync` is very particular about how options are written:

```
--exclude=backup
```

*alternative*:

```
--exclude '*dir'
```

**Other Suggestions:**

1. Remove trailing slashes on variables (rsync is very specific about `/`)
2. For command subsitution use `$( ... )` instead of backticks (if available/possible)
3. Eliminate redundant code (eg. you define `$BACKUPDIR` but only use it once effectively)
4. When having issues always use the `--verbose` option, it really helps with rsync

**Revised Script:**

```
#!/bin/env bash

# export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin

# directory to backup
TOSAVE=$HOME/thingstobackup
TODAY=$(date +%F)
BDIR=backup
BACKUPDIR=$TOSAVE/$BDIR/$TODAY

# options for rsync
OPTS="-raq --exclude=$BDIR --exclude=$TODAY"

# find daily new file
FIND=$(find $TOSAVE -mindepth 1 -mtime -1 -print)

# MAIN #
# copy daily found inside new created daily folder
[ -d $BACKUPDIR ] || mkdir -p $BACKUPDIR
rsync $OPTS $FIND $BACKUPDIR

# delete file older than 2 weeks = 14 days
find $TOSAVE -mtime +14 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Most of the changes are in the way the paths are constructed for`thingstobackup`:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

Running the script it would then appear like:

```
file1   
file2   
file3   // files that will be included to rsync destination
|
|_______backup   // exclude=$BDIR should not be included
        |
        |________2016-01-14   // exlude=$TODAY would also be advised
                  file1
                  file2
                  file3
```

EDIT: In order for rsync to not break when encountering a filename containing spaces you'll want to handle that in your `find` method.
* You could likely refine your script further by using rsync commands instead of `find` altogether, but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Mate this is awesome! I can't check it now because I'm already out of the office but tomorrow this will be the first thing to do.
True, your revision looks much better! Thank you (:

Comment: #!/bin/env bash I know already that this does not work because I tried at the beginning and then I switched to the old #!/bin/bash
JFYI

Comment: Yeah it depends on which version of bash you have whether or not you can use the newer command substitution, so use backticks if needed. One other thing I didn't point out is that files with spaces could cause problems... So you might want to look into dealing with that if it's a concern. Cheers! :)

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) - the server is Ubuntu 14.04.3 and I don't think I will ever move this script or use in another system.. I just stick with old shebang !

I tried it (and yes it needs the old shebang) and there is a problem, it copies the folder of yesterday (2016-01-14) inside the $TODAY

Comment: Does it copy $THEDAYBEFORE inside $TODAY also? If so then I would recommend setting up another filter or ditching the `find` method altogether, as `rsync` should have the capability to do his on it's own.

Comment: Yes it copies the folder of yesterday inside the $TODAY and not the "backup". Anyway, it is not that clean and at the end I use rsync as if it is just the CP command.. but it works as I want when I let the FIND do all the job.. so I'm ok.. Of course if you or anyone end up with a better solution I'll be glad to use it but at the moment the find works pretty good ;)